# How To Capture Target Process With FiddlerCore

Tags: c#, fiddler, fiddlercore

My code is currently captures all browser traffic but i want to capture target process ( browser )

I start browser with Process.Start and then I need only this browser traffic.

```
private void InitializeFiddler()
{
    FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete += FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete;
    FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);

    WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
    Uri newUri = new Uri("http://localhost:8888");
    myProxy.Address = newUri;

    Process.Start("http://stackoverflow.com/");
}

private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session oSession)
{
    if (oSession.fullUrl.Contains(".mp3"))
    {    
        _streamUrl = oSession.fullUrl.Substring(0, oSession.fullUrl.Length - 5); ;          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer:

```
private void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Session oSession)
{
    if (oSession.LocalProcessID == 1234)
    {
        //
    }
}
```